# How to modify minicart.js Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

Without editing the core file, I want to add some code to **`minicart.js`** so I tried overriding the **`minicart.js`** file in my theme by this:

> **var/www/animals/app/design/frontend/Dogs/husky/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js**

But it did not work? Am I doing something wrong?

THANKS!

Comment: Try deleting static content using `rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*` and flush the cache. You'll need to redeploy static content if you're in production mode.

Answer (score 8):

You'd better extend the minicart component. For example:

> **app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/checkout/view/minicart': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> **app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout/view/minicart.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            initialize: function () {
                var self = this;

                return this._super();
            },
        });
    }
});
```

More info [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) and study more about jquery ui-components for extra help below:

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html
> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html
> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html

Comment: I follow the same steps and extended closing event in minicart.js  but it's not working.

Comment: Can you describe your problem a bit more (with code fragments and such) please?

Comment: The filename is not `requirejs.config`, it's `requirejs-config.js`

Comment: Thx for reporting, updated.